# Qemu: dual display with VGA passthrough AND virtual display device?

Tags: virtualization, qemu

I'm evaluating a move from VirtualBox to Qemu / Libvirt, largely because I want to play with VGA passthrough.  I have a basic system running now.

I want my Windows VM to have dual displays, with both the passed-through NVidia display AND a virtual display.  (Ultimately, I'd like to find a way to clone the hardware display to the virtual display, [perhaps with third-party software](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/3qf15q/gpu_passthrough_one_monitor/cweqy0n/).)

When I keep the QXL virtual display in a VM that has the passthrough GPU, it reports error `Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)`.  Is this worth trying to troubleshoot?

TLDR: Can I run a VM with a virtual display AND passthrough VGA?  Can I mirror one to the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question had some poor assumptions.

- The code 43 is [NVidia's way of preventing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41362981/nvidia-gpu-passthrough-fail-with-code-43) you from emulating CUDA performance with commodity hardware.
- I haven't yet found a way to run QXL/Spice and a passed-through GPU, but [xfreerdp has done a pretty good job](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/403989/196978) of meeting my needs.

EDIT:

[Looking-glass](https://looking-glass.hostfission.com/) doesn't precisely answer the question, but it solves the underlying problem nearly perfectly  -- providing GPU-accelerated VM graphics on the host desktop.  In alpha as of Dec 2017, but appears stable enough for everyday use on a single display.